# Moving backwards from fragment

Tags: android

> Fragment InvoiceInfo

```
public void move_to_another_fragment() {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) new ItemFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Items");
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack("invoiceinfo").commit();

}
```

In the Above fragment Invoice Info I use *move_to_another_fragment* method to move into Fragment *PurchaseOrder* it works fine

> Fragment PurchaseOrder

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("purchase_order");
fm.popBackStack();
```

This Fragment *PurchaseOrder* has a button, when the button is clicked it should go back to the previous page(InvoiceInfo fragment). 
It also works but when I click a button in invoice frgament I need to go to the PurchaseOrder.

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("purchase_order");
fm.popBackStack();
```

I used the above code inside the *InvoiceInfo* fragment to do that but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried popBackStackImmediate()?

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
```

**update**

```
  FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack ("invoiceinfo", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: not working.i actually i need to get the any fragment reside in the stack instead of taking top one.

Comment: @SupunLakshan edited my answer check if it works for you